# Unable to separate csv's into separate columns

Tags: r

I have used the following function to create a unique data_frame with csv's (already encoded in UTF-8 form):

```
library(readr)
comentarios_hoteles<-list.files(path="C:/Users/OneDrive/Documentos/DFBA/ Melia", pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE) %>%
  lapply(read_csv)%>%                                            
  bind_rows
```

For some reason I am getting all the observations in one column instead of in 6.

```
This is the full code:
Comentario,"Fecha","Mes","Estación","Hotel","Marca"
1   No todas las instalaciones del hotel se pudieron usar, estaban cerradas sin avisar previamente al cliente. Se intentó hacer un cambio en las fechas de la reserva debido al temporal de calima que hubo (no porque no quisiéramos irnos de hotel) y no dejaron (añadiendo que el tiempo estaba mucho mejor que el día anterior) y tampoco propusieron solución. Al llegar al hotel, vemos que la piscina está cerrada por dicho temporal, por lo que encima no se podía disfrutar de todas las instalaciones. Los desayunos muy bien, variados. No puedo decir lo mismo de las cenas: arroz pasado y con olor, poca variedad y para colmo los camareros sirviéndose la cena sin darte paso a ti, cliente, a servite no siendo que le quitaramos el trozo de pizza que quería... En fin... Yo siempre que voy a hotel, voy a los Melia, pero este en concreto no está a la altura de lo que acostumbra la marca, por lo que no lo recomendaría. …,2020-02-01,"feb.","Invierno","Sol Arona Tenerife","Sol"
2   Me he ido con un buen sabor de boca, y ganas de volver. Me ha sorprendido totalmente el hotel.  Nuestra habitación en la planta 14, era genial! Espaciosa, bien cuidada, vistas preciosas, limpieza bien.  Servicio de restaurante con horario amplio. El día de comida mexicana, un acierto total!! Me encantó.  Eché de menos la nata en el desayuno, para las tortitas, gofres y demás. Aunque había sirope de sobra! Camareros, y recepcionistas, muy atent@os. Especial agradecimiento a Bela, de recepción, siempre muy amable con nosotros.  Volveré, y pronto!!! ,2019-11-01,"nov.","Otoño","Sol Arona Tenerife","Sol"
3   Hotel normalito. Está un poco viejo. Las habitaciones no tienen aire acondicionado. Las animaciones por la noche son muy cortas, están principalmente enfocadas para el turismo extranjero y empiezan muy pronto. En mi opinión, las instalaciones no están a la altura de un hotel de 4 estrellas. Lo que más nos gusto, fue el trato del personal del buffet, destacando al camarero Roberto, que nos hizo una estancia mucho más agradable y amena, siempre con una atención maravillosa en el restaurante, y ayudándonos y recomendándonos en cuanto a las actividades que queríamos realizar en la isla,  demostrando  ser un gran profesional que disfruta de su trabajo y siempre con una sonrisa.,2019-09-01,"sep.","Verano","Sol Arona Tenerife","Sol"
4   Tenemos dos niños pequeños por lo que contratar el hotel con pensión todo incluído nos viene muy cómodo. Por otro lado el hotel está cerca de tiendas, farmacias y una clínica por si hay alguna incidencia. Además el hotel está a 5 minutos a pie de la playa de los Cristianos por lo que es muy conveniente.,2020-02-01,"feb.","Invierno","Sol Arona Tenerife","Sol"
5   habitacion de albergue , 20 metros cuadrados para 5 personas incluyendo un bebé ,cama litera de peligro ,  a 180€ por noche deja que desear , la Directira del hotel incapaz de solucionar nuestro reclamo.  Buen buffet y localización , nada más - no volveremos , rato en un Meliá,2020-01-01,"ene.","Invierno","Sol Arona Tenerife","Sol"
6   Bastante bien para unas vacaciones por el sur, Cerca del muelle y de la playa. Se puede ir a pie por los paseos cercanos, Las habitaciones un poco viejas. Pero si vas a dormir y a disfrutar de la isla. Buena relación calidad-precio,2019-12-01,"dic.","Invierno","Sol Arona Tenerife","Sol"
7   Tuvimos el lavabo atascado y tuvimos que reclamar varias veces su arreglo. Camas incomodas. Todo muy viejo. El bufet malísimo  y sin variedad. Las animaciones y los horarios pensados para extranjeros solamente. Hay un camarero en el bufet de cena que es un pesado. Solamente hablando mal del hotel y de su administración. Desde luego no volveremos. Fuimos cuando era Princesa Dácil y ha sido una decepción.,2019-12-01,"dic.","Invierno","Sol Arona Tenerife","Sol"
8   puede parecer en un principio q es de la cadena Melia y asi debio ser en sus comienzos, a dia de hoy es bastante normalito tirando a básico, lo elegi para pasar diez días por eso mismo pensando q tenia la calidad de todo el grupo Melia, incluso antes de reservarlo me dijeron q aplicaban el programa de puntos cosa q no hicieron, por q no se había reservado directamente con ellos, si no a través de un operador(FALLO-MALTRATO AL CLIENTE)pero por teléfono te cuentan lo q quieres oir......el bufett es bastante bueno todo hay q decirlo y en cuanto a las habitaciones normalitas sin lujos pero limpias y en buen estado ,2019-01-01,"ene.","Invierno","Sol Arona Tenerife","Sol"
9   Nos alojamos un fin de semana en régimen de todo incluido y la experiencia no fue mala exceptuando algunas cosas. La habitación era grande y espaciosa, además estaba todo muy limpio. Lo malo es que la cama era muy incómoda y con muchos muelles, pero nos lo solucionaron ese mismo día y pudimos dormir decentemente. A pesar de ello, creo que un hotel de estas características debería tener una cama mucho mejor.  Nos vamos descontentos con el tema del todo incluido. Las bebidas eran muy malas. La comida no estaba mala de sabor, pero faltaba variedad en el almuerzo ya que durante los días que estuvimos comimos casi lo mismo. En la cena si que ponían algo más diferente. Los desayunos estaban muy bien pero desde las 10 empiezan a quitar las comida, algo que creo que no debería suceder…,2019-12-01,"dic.","Invierno","Sol Arona Tenerife","Sol"
10  No es la primera vez que me hospedo por lo que me parece
```

Would greatly appreciate some help with this error as I am not able to solve it. Thank you in advance1

Comment: Please don't use images to show code, data, or console output; edit your question by copy-pasting it. You may also want to provide an excerpt of your .csv file.

Comment: Just changed it, hope it helps

Comment: Can you try `comentarios_hoteles<-list.files(path="C:/Users/OneDrive/Documentos/DFBA/Sol Melia", pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE) %>%purrr::map_df(read.csv)`

Comment: Yes it gives me:Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  no lines available in input

Comment: Yeah it's better. The problem might be, that the "Comentario"s are not in quotes `""` and include a `,`. The `sep=`aration argument of `read.csv` also wants to use it. Hence when you use `sep=","` it divides commentarios into columns, and wen you use no sep you have just everything in one column.

Comment: Why don't the commentarios not have quotes? Which program generated the .csv?

Comment: I saved the csv files as UTF-8 csv files (delimited by commas). Don't know if this may have something to do with the issue

Comment: You should check the real structure of your file by opening the csv into a raw editor (no word) or read the file 1 line at the time (e.g. `readLines`). There you should udnerstand what the deliter and quotes of your files are.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the separator in your csv file is different to the one being used by `read.csv`, which is `""` by default.  Perhaps you need, `sep=","`. But, as @jay.sf says, it's impossible to be sure without seeing your input data.

To specify a different separator in a call to `lapply` try

```
... lapply(function(x) read_csv(x, sep=",")) ...
```

For more information, pleaseread the online documentaion: `?read.csv` should give you all you need.

Here's a simple-self contained example showing you how to use `read.csv` with `lapply`.  if you still have problems after using this approach, then the problem lies in your source data.  There's little more we can do without seeing your input files.

```
library(tidyverse)

d1 <- tibble(x=runif(5), y=runif(5))
d2 <- tibble(x=runif(5), y=runif(5))
d3 <- tibble(x=runif(5), y=runif(5))
# write.csv uses "," as the separator by default
write.csv(d1, "d1.csv")
write.csv(d2, "d2.csv")
write.csv(d3, "d3.csv")

# Using .Platform$file.sep as it looks like you're using Windows and I'm using OS X
lapply(1:3, function(x) read.csv(paste0(getwd(), .Platform$file.sep, "d", x, ".csv"), sep=",")) %>% bind_rows()
```

Giving

```
   X         x          y
1  1 0.9252148 0.56729752
2  2 0.5308788 0.16184362
3  3 0.3117391 0.98391774
4  4 0.7920537 0.09282097
5  5 0.9170348 0.19527942
6  1 0.5205679 0.53923853
7  2 0.8024267 0.45252059
8  3 0.9495656 0.42110252
9  4 0.9276184 0.71073388
10 5 0.6631055 0.99259850
11 1 0.9946208 0.52989414
12 2 0.8580251 0.69050776
13 3 0.5421475 0.26334383
14 4 0.9130681 0.15021119
15 5 0.3810522 0.08094137
```

Comment: Hi Limey, thanks for your answer. I have tried comentarios_hoteles<-list.files(path="C:/Users/julhe/OneDrive/Documentos/DFBA/Sol Melia", pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE) %>%
  lapply(read_csv(sep=","))%>%                                            
  bind_rows                                           but it returnsError in read_csv(sep = ",") : unused argument (sep = ",")

Comment: For some reason I am still getting unused argument (sep = ",")

Comment: Added another edit.  The reason we are not able to help you effectively is that you are not providing a simple self contained example.

Comment: I just solved it! It appears to be a prblem related with how I was downloading csv's instead of how I was merging them. I repeated the scraping to obtain my csv and by putting options(encoding="utf-8") instead of saving it as csv and then setting it as CSV UTF-8, it gives a normal dataframe. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: A clasic example of the importance of providing your input data.  If we'd have had that, we could have homed in on the real problem far more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The `commentario` part of your .csv file have no quotes `""` and use commas `,` which are usually used to separate the text into columns from functions to read .csv files. .csv is abbreviated for **c**omma **s**eparated **v**alues. Now, the separation algorithm gets confused because it doesn't know, whether a comma is part of a comment or should be used to separate into a column.

You could use `readLines` to juest read the plain lines. Then you may use `gsub` with a regex that converts the "hot" commas (where to separate) into something different, e.g. `;`, which you then use to `sep`arate into columns.

Try the following.

```
A <- readLines(con <- file("V:/commentarios.csv"))
close(con)

## enquote dates
csv <-  gsub('(.*)(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})(.*)"', '\\1\\"\\2\\"\\3', A)

## convert "hot" commas into ";"
csv <-  gsub('\\"\\,\\"', '\\"\\;\\"', csv)
## convert "hot" commas that appear before a date
csv <-  gsub('\\,\\"', '\\;\\"', csv)

## finally read the .csv
res <- read.csv(text=csv, header=TRUE, sep=";", quote="")
#            Comentario     X.Fecha. X.Mes. X.Estación.             X.Hotel. X.Marca.
# 1  1   No todas la... "2020-02-01" "feb."  "Invierno" "Sol Arona Tenerife"     "Sol
# 2  2   Me he ido c... "2019-11-01" "nov."     "Otoño" "Sol Arona Tenerife"     "Sol
# 3  3   Hotel norma... "2019-09-01" "sep."    "Verano" "Sol Arona Tenerife"     "Sol
# 4  4   Tenemos dos... "2020-02-01" "feb."  "Invierno" "Sol Arona Tenerife"     "Sol
# 5  5   habitacion ... "2020-01-01" "ene."  "Invierno" "Sol Arona Tenerife"     "Sol
# 6  6   Bastante bi... "2019-12-01" "dic."  "Invierno" "Sol Arona Tenerife"     "Sol
# 7  7   Tuvimos el ... "2019-12-01" "dic."  "Invierno" "Sol Arona Tenerife"     "Sol
# 8  8   puede parec... "2019-01-01" "ene."  "Invierno" "Sol Arona Tenerife"     "Sol
# 9  9   Nos alojamo... "2019-12-01" "dic."  "Invierno" "Sol Arona Tenerife"     "Sol
# 10 10  No es la pr...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, it erases the majority of information from the column Comentarios

Comment: @Maria What information, could you elaborate on that? Is the .csv content you provided in your question really identical to the raw content, i.e. when you open it with a text editor as e.g. notepad.exe on windows?

Comment: Yes, I have just changed the csv with excel so that the column comentario is in "", but now it gives me 1: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  entrada inválida encontrada en la conexión de entrada 'ReseÃ±as1.csv'
2: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'ReseÃ±as1.csv'

Comment: @Maria Open .csv with notepad.exe, go to end of last line and type return (to add line break), save the file and try again.

Comment: Thanks!Just solved it by redowloading csv files and setting first options(encoding = "utf-8"), instead of changing csv to csv UTF-8 later